# Create scratch org with Enhanced Email activated

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, enhanced-emails

I am trying to automate the creation of scratch orgs, when trying to install a needed managed packaged after scratch org creation I get this error:

```
ERROR running force:package:install:report:  Installation errors: 
1) Missing Organization Feature: EnhancedEmail
```

I need to activate that feature without doing it manually. I have reviewed the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) and I haven't found anything useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In you scratch org definition file you need to enable Enhanced Email if it is not automatically enabled and seems like it is not.

you need

```
    "emailAdministrationSettings": {
        "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true
    }
```

Comment: thank you! that worked! Thanks to that info I found the related doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_settings.htm https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailadministrationsettings.htm. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help. 
Would you mind marking the answer?

Comment: done: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.